# can read elements with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I use webdriver to read some elements from this website [bmce.bank](https://www.bmcebank.ma/fr/nos-agences?p=178&v=132) , I want to take informations about bank agencies , all elements in html are visible but I can only read first 3 elements . like if I have to scroll down the tab .
here's the function that read the tab :

```
def lire_items(self, driver,ville):
    items = []
    tabs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("result") 
    for tab in tabs:
        tel = tab.find_element_by_class_name('tel')
        item = {
                "name" : tab.find_element_by_class_name('name').text,
                "adress" : tab.find_element_by_class_name('adresse').text ,
                "city" : ville,
                "fax" : '',
                "tel" : tel.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text,
                "bank" : 'bmce',
            }
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

and here's an example of the output :
[image: csv.file]

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 3 elements are visible - the others are hidden

If you need to get values of the hidden elements, just use `get_attribute('textContent')` instead of `text`, e.g.

```
"name" : tab.find_element_by_class_name('name').get_attribute('textContent')
```

Comment: thanks , it worked . i ve been scraping for long time , but i never knew this method :)